# Custom theme showing a white page in ASP.NET Zero

Tags: asp.net, themes, loading, metronic

I am currently working on a project in the ASP.NET Zero framework and I am trying to create a custom Metronic theme. I started by copying an existing theme and used the documentation to add a new version of that theme but with a different name.

I followed every step in the documentation and I have also searched in the whole project for the places where the themes get implemented. Everything after this looks ok and I can see the theme in my theme selections.

But the problem is when I chose the theme and save it, then the page won't show anything. I only see a white page. The settings, however, get updated with the correct theme and if I inspect the network tap in the browser, then I see that everything is loaded without problems. There are also no errors to be found. I don't understand what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Do you have any code in Application_Error of global.asax file. If yes you may remove it which will show you an actual error.

Comment: Hmm, I just looked in my project structure, I can't find a global.asax file. I have also just noticed something. The html is also loaded and if I like play a bit with the css, then I can instantly see the changed on the page.

Comment: Good! what did you change?

Comment: Nothing, I am still with the same problem :c